# ADB and cloned VBox emulators - not detected

Tags: android, adb, virtualbox, emulation

I want to provide each user of my application a separate android emulator in the background. To achieve this, I clone the VMs in the following way:

```
vboxmanage clonevm <uuid> --snapshot <suuid> --name test_clone1 --register
vboxmanage clonevm <uuid> --snapshot <suuid> --name test_clone2 --register

vboxmanage startvm test_clone1
vboxmanage startvm test_clone2
```

Both VMs are created and started correctly. However, running ADB, the tools merely recognizes one of them:

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

The original VM has 2 Network adapters, one host-only, the other one NAT with TCP port 5555 forwarded. Further, they have a different IP address after startup.

Can somebody help what I have to change in the settings/creation of the clones so that ADB recognizes all clones?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I did find a way

```
adb connect <clone1_ip>:<port>
adb connect <clone2_ip>:<port>
```

Now both are showing up when I issue adb devices.